# Optimize vector matrix multiplication in cuda with large number of zeros

Tags: cuda, cublas

I am using the following kernel to optimize vector-matrix multiplication for the case where both the vector and the matrix have a large number of zeros. The use of this kernel **may reduce** the time taken for such a multiplication by **up to half** of the time taken by cublasSgemv, for the case where there are more than 90% zeros. But, it is still much **longer than an equivalent blas gemm** host call on Ubuntu 14.04

vec = 1 x m, mat = m x m and prod = 1 x m; all are in row-major order

m >= 5000

```
__global__ void calc_v_m(float *vec, float *mat, float *prod, int m)      
{
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(x < m)
    {
        prod[x] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int offset = i*m + x;
            if( mat[offset] != 0 && vec[i] != 0 )       
                prod[x] += vec[i] * mat[i*m+x];
       }
    }
}
```

What can be done to further enhance the performance of this kernel apart from libraries like cuSparse?

Would be nice if this optimization was compatible with Compute Capability of 1.2

Thanks

**EDIT**

Corrected: prod = 1 x m

GPU = Quadro FX 1800M, Cuda v.5.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

**EDIT**

Complete code that performs multiplication using i. blas, ii. cublas, iii. above kernel  for m = 6000. Please enter 0, when asked to enter a value

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

const int m = 6000; 
const int BS = 512; // threads per block
const int NB = ceil((float) m / BS); // number of blocks

__global__ void calc_v_m(float *vec, float *mat, float *prod, int m)  
{
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(x < m)
    {
        prod[x] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int offset = i*m + x;
            if( mat[offset] != 0 && vec[i] != 0 )       
                prod[x] += vec[i] * mat[i*m+x];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
timespec blas_start, blas_end, cublas_start, cublas_end, opt_start, opt_end;
long totalnsec; //total nano sec
double totalsec, totaltime;
int i, j;

float *A = new float[m]; // 1 x m
float *B = new float[m*m]; // m x m
float *C = new float[m]; // 1 x m

float input;
cout<<"Enter a value to populate the vector (0 to make it sparse) ";
cin>>input;

// input martix A: every 600th element is non-zero i.e 90% zero
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
{       
    A[i] = input;
    if( i % 600 == 0)    //adjust for sparsity
            A[i] = i;
}

// input matrix B: identity matrix
for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
                B[j*m + i] = (i==j);

//blas on host
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &blas_start);
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 1, m, m, 1.0f, A, m, B, m, 0.0f, C, m);
//cblas_sgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, m, m, 1.0f, B, m, A, 1, 0.0f, C, 1);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &blas_end);

/* for(i = 0; i < m; i++) printf("%f ", C[i]); */

//cublas section
cudaError_t cudaStat;   
cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasCreate(&handle);
float *A_d, *B_d, *C_d;

cudaStat = cudaMalloc(&A_d, sizeof(float)*m);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess) printf("Error Allocating Memory for A_d\n");

cudaStat = cudaMalloc(&B_d, sizeof(float)*m*m);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess) printf("Error Allocating Memory for B_d\n");

cudaStat = cudaMalloc(&C_d, sizeof(float)*m);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess) printf("Error Allocating Memory for C_d\n");

cudaMemcpy(A_d, A, sizeof(float)*m, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(B_d, B, sizeof(float)*m*m, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

float alpha = 1.0f, beta = 0.0f;

cudaDeviceSynchronize();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &cublas_start);
cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, m, &alpha, B_d, m, A_d, 1, &beta, C_d, 1);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &cublas_end);

cudaMemcpy(C, C_d, sizeof(float)*m, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);    
/* for(i = 0; i < m; i++) printf("%f ", C[i]); */ 

// Call kernel having Optimization for Zeros
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &opt_start);
/////////////////// call kernel //////////////////
calc_v_m<<<NB, BS>>>(A_d, B_d, C_d,  m);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &opt_end);

cudaMemcpy(C, C_d, sizeof(float)*m, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);    
/*for(i = 0; i < m; i++) printf("%f ", C[i]); */

// Print times
// blas time
totalsec = (double)blas_end.tv_sec - (double)blas_start.tv_sec;
totalnsec = blas_end.tv_nsec - blas_start.tv_nsec;
if(totalnsec < 0)
{
    totalnsec += 1e9;
    totalsec -= 1;
}   
totaltime = totalsec + (double)totalnsec*1e-9;
cout<<"blas Time = "<< totaltime << "\n";

//cublas time
totalsec = (double)cublas_end.tv_sec - (double)cublas_start.tv_sec;
totalnsec = cublas_end.tv_nsec - cublas_start.tv_nsec;
if(totalnsec < 0)
{
    totalnsec += 1e9;
    totalsec -= 1;
}
totaltime = totalsec + (double)totalnsec*1e-9;
cout<<"cublas Time = "<< totaltime << "\n";

//Optimized Kernel Time
totalsec = (double)opt_end.tv_sec - (double)opt_start.tv_sec;
totalnsec = opt_end.tv_nsec - opt_start.tv_nsec;
if(totalnsec < 0)
{
     totalnsec += 1e9;
     totalsec -= 1;
}
totaltime = totalsec + (double)totalnsec*1e-9;
cout<<"Opt Kernel Time = "<< totaltime << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Results

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_12 blascomp.cu -o blascomp.o -lblas -lcublas
$ ./blascomp.o
Enter a value to populate the vector (0 to make it sparse) 0
blas Time = 0.000105207
cublas Time = 0.0070294
Opt Kernel Time = 0.00642797
```

At least on my system blas is still the fastest for such a scenario

Things get even more interesting if every '1200th' element instead of '600th' is set to 0

```
Enter a value to populate the vector (0 to make it sparse) 0
blas Time = 7.84e-05
cublas Time = 0.00698783
Opt Kernel Time = 0.00643042
```

Comment: prod = 1xm, not mxm.  the result of a matrix-vector (or vector-matrix) multiply is a vector, not a matrix.   Put `vec` in `__constant__` memory (for `m` up to about 16000 `float`). Provide a full test case for comparison - including timing of both the GPU and CPU versions you are comparing.  Also provide relevant details like CUDA version and GPU you are running on.

Comment: `b` and `a` aren't defined anywhere in your kernel, so you're obviously not running that code.   Why not post the code that you actually did the timing measurement on to make this claim: "The use of this kernel reduces the time taken for such a multiplication by up to half of the time taken by cublasSgemv, for the case where there are more than 90% zeros."

Comment: @RobertCrovella : This kernel is even faster: `__global__ void calc_v_m(float *vec, float *mat, float *prod, int m) { }`. Up to 100% faster, to be precise.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: sorry for the errors. I changed arg names to be meaningful after pasting in the post but forgot to change in the condition. I will post the complete code very soon. Thx

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I have uploaded the complete source file along with my results

Comment: @RobertCrovella: "...... **by up to** half of the time taken by cublasSgemv, for the case ........." I was not advocating for it be a good kernel and I thought that **at best** this kernel could gain **up to** half of cublasSgemv's efficiency. Whereas, my question was that could it be improved to match the performance of blas gemm which as you can see, in the results given above, is much much better. Maybe I was a little loose with my words.

Comment: @Marco13: would be grateful if you gave the complete code now available in the question a try on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This is completely silly. When I run your code on my Ubuntu 14 system, CBLAS is 100 times *slower* than CUBLAS and 10 times slower than your "Optimal Kernel".

Comment: While it is comparatively simple to gain a good speedup for certain BLAS operations on the GPU, it is hard to do this for *sparse* operations. There's a reason why CUSPARSE exists and has such a "complicated" API. Regarding your kernel: GPUs are bad at branches. Even when you insert sth. like `if( mat[offset] != 0...)`, then the computation will still be done, even if the condition does **not** hold. (It will only ignore the results, using "predicated execution"). I doubt that it is possible to exploit the sparsity of the data without *modelling* it, but maybe someone can prove me wrong...

Comment: @talonmies Refrain from using words like "silly" because they expose your shallowness of intellect and lack of maturity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to recognise here is that the gemv operation you are concerned with is fundamentally memory throughput limited on GPUs, rather than compute throughput limited. This implies that an "optimisation" as you have shown in your kernel:

```
__global__ void calc_v_m(float *vec, float *mat, float *prod, int m)  
{
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(x < m)
    {
        prod[x] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int offset = i*m + x;
            if( mat[offset] != 0 && vec[i] != 0 )       
                prod[x] += vec[i] * mat[i*m+x];
        }
    }
}
```

isn't really an optmisation at all, simply because the memory transactions are the performance bottleneck in the kernel, not the floating point arithmetic, and your code must perform most of the memory transactions irrespective of whether the multiply add operation will be performed because of zero detection or not.

Consider the following, instrumented version of roughly the same code:

```
__constant__ float cvec1[2];
__global__ void 
__launch_bounds__(512,4)    
calc_v_m1(const float* __restrict__ vec,
          const float* __restrict__ mat, 
          float* __restrict__ prod, 
          int m,
          int do_reads = 1,
          int do_write = 1)
{
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(x < m)
    {
        float res = 0;
        float mval = cvec1[0], vval = cvec1[1];
#pragma unroll 8
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int offset = i*m + x;
            if (do_reads) {
                mval = mat[offset];
                vval = vec[i];
            } 
            res += mval * vval;
        }
        if (do_write) prod[x] = res;
    }
}
```

Here I have added two optional arguments which control whether the kernel will load from global memory, and whether the kernel will store to global memory. This allows me to quantify the performance impact of the memory loads, computation, and memory stores independently. The results using your test code are instructive:

```
Function                            nvprof time
-----------------------------------------------
cublasSgemv                         942.75us
calc_v_m                            2798.4us
calc_v_m1(do_reads=1, do_write=1)   962.40us
calc_v_m1(do_reads=1, do_write=0)   970.40us
calc_v_m1(do_reads=0, do_write=1)   55.166us
calc_v_m1(do_reads=0, do_write=0)   55.102us
```

[All benchmarking done on a GTX970 using the CUDA 7.5 release toolchain and CUBLAS 7.5 library]

In no particular order:

- The full instrumented kernel runtime is within a few percent of the equivalent CUBLAS call
- The memory fetches from global memory are the bottleneck
- The actual computations in the kernel only constitute 5% of the kernel running time
- The "fire-and-forget" nature of write operations in CUDA means that the latency of the write has no significant effect on throughput.
- Your "optimised" kernel is considerably slower than either CUBLAS or the instrumented kernel, probably because all you are introducing is branch divergence without addressing the source of the kernel bottleneck (the latency of the memory loads).

The only times conditionally executing the FMAD operation makes sense would be in an architecture where memory has near zero latency and floating point throughput was severely constrained. The GPU definitely doesn't fall into that category.

The only other option for optimising this would be to exploit *a priori* information about the sparsity patterns in the LHS matrix to remove the need to read zero entries. Which is precisely what sparse matrix formats and linear algebra codes are designed to accommodate.